# Generate Unique Number Company Wise + Year Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table containing columns: `PurchaseOrderID`, `CompanyID` and `CreatedDate`. I want a column named `PONo` in this table that will automatically have values from previous column like : PO/2016(Year from `CreatedDate`)/001(value will increment for same year and same company id).

My expected table is as below:

```
PurchaseOrderID    CompanyID    PONo            CreatedDate
1                      1        PO/2016/001     2016-01-31
2                      1        PO/2016/002     2016-02-22
3                      1        PO/2016/003     2016-05-25
4                      2        PO/2016/001     2016-09-1
5                      2        PO/2016/002     2016-10-11
6                      2        PO/2016/003     2016-12-31
7                      1        PO/2017/001     2017-01-31
8                      1        PO/2017/002     2017-02-2
9                      1        PO/2017/003     2017-05-20
10                     2        PO/2017/001     2017-06-25
11                     2        PO/2017/002     2017-07-15
12                     2        PO/2017/003     2017-08-22
```

From This table I want to generate and update PONo like above table.
I want query to generate PONo.

When I insert new record in table then PONo generates automatically from this record.

Note: If need to add any column let me know.

Comment: The question is unclear. Is this the expected result? Do you want a query that generates PONo?

Comment: not understood 'generate and update PONo like table'??

Comment: Yes. I want to know how PONo is generates by using query.

Comment: you want to generate 'PONo' by concatenate the columns?

Comment: You can easily generate the values of `PONo` using `CONCAT` and `ROW_NUMBER`. I suggest that you don't store these values permanently in a table column as this would incur a big overhead of maintaining the column values in case a new record is added into the table.

Comment: @Ketul, You can do this at the time of insert.

Answer (score 2):

You may looking for this

```
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT PurchaseOrderID,
               CompanyID,
               CreatedDate,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID,YEAR(CreatedDate) ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS RN
        FROM TableName
)
SELECT PurchaseOrderID,
       CompanyID,
       'PO/'+CAST(YEAR(CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(5))+'/'+RIGHT('00'+CAST(RN AS VRACHAR(5),3)),
       CreatedDate
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    PurchaseOrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyID int NOT NULL,
    PONo CHAR(11) NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData(PurchaseOrderID, CompanyID, CreatedDate) VALUES
    (1 , 1, '2016-01-31'),
    (2 , 1, '2016-02-22'),
    (3 , 1, '2016-05-25'),
    (4 , 2, '2016-09-01'),
    (5 , 2, '2016-10-11'),
    (6 , 2, '2016-12-31'),
    (7 , 1, '2017-01-31'),
    (8 , 1, '2017-02-02'),
    (9 , 1, '2017-05-20'),
    (10, 2, '2017-06-25'),
    (11, 2, '2017-07-15'),
    (12, 2, '2017-08-22');

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--=========================================

SELECT 
    *,
    PONo = CONCAT('PO/', YEAR(td.CreatedDate), '/', RIGHT(CONCAT('000', 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.CompanyID, YEAR(td.CreatedDate) ORDER BY td.PurchaseOrderID)), 3))
FROM
    #TestData td;
```

Results...

```
PurchaseOrderID CompanyID   PONo        CreatedDate PONo
--------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------
1               1           NULL        2016-01-31  PO/2016/001
2               1           NULL        2016-02-22  PO/2016/002
3               1           NULL        2016-05-25  PO/2016/003
7               1           NULL        2017-01-31  PO/2017/001
8               1           NULL        2017-02-02  PO/2017/002
9               1           NULL        2017-05-20  PO/2017/003
4               2           NULL        2016-09-01  PO/2016/001
5               2           NULL        2016-10-11  PO/2016/002
6               2           NULL        2016-12-31  PO/2016/003
10              2           NULL        2017-06-25  PO/2017/001
11              2           NULL        2017-07-15  PO/2017/002
12              2           NULL        2017-08-22  PO/2017/003
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate new sequence logic.

```
CREATE TABLE PO_wise_seq
(
    PO      BIGINT,
    year_   INT,
    seq     BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) 
)

DECLARE @PO_ID BIGINT =332
DECLARE @Year_id BIGINT =2016

INSERT INTO PO_wise_seq VALUES (@PO_ID,@Year_id)

select PO,
cast(@PO_ID as nvarchar) +'/' +cast(@Year_id as nvarchar)+'/'+cast(count(1) as nvarchar) as seq
FROM PO_wise_seq
WHERE PO=@PO_ID
    AND year_=@Year_id
GROUP BY PO,year_
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate new sequence logic.

```
CREATE TABLE PO_wise_seq
(
    CompanyID       BIGINT,
    year_   INT,
    seq     BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) 
)

DECLARE @CompanyID BIGINT =332
DECLARE @Year_id BIGINT =2016

INSERT INTO PO_wise_seq VALUES (@CompanyID,@Year_id)

select CompanyID
    ,cast(@CompanyID as nvarchar) +'/' +cast(@Year_id as nvarchar)+'/'+cast(count(1) as nvarchar) as seq
FROM PO_wise_seq
WHERE CompanyID=@CompanyID
    AND year_=@Year_id
GROUP BY CompanyID,year_
```